# Offline Transit Routing Algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, routes, android-maps, openstreetmap

I am developing an offline maps & navigation app for Android as my final year project. The application has to provide transit route planning similar to the way Google Transit does. Currently I am working on a small city as a prototype and efficiency is not an issue right now.

However I'm unaware of any off-the-shelf Java frameworks that would help me implement such a feature, nor am I aware of any algorithms to help me code my own.

Can anyone instruct me on where to start, either by pointing me to code examples of this, or at least routing theory pages to assist me in coding my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theory & Algorithms:**
If you haven't already read about it, the [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) is mainly the challenge that most journey planning algorithms are dealing with. On the wiki page, read the "Algorithms" section for a list of possible solutions ([Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is probably the most popular). There are some algorithm variations specifically for public transport, such as [RAPTOR](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=156567).

**Model & Journey Planner:**
Depending on the scope of your work, it could be over the top to design a model and to implement the whole journey planner on your own.

I would suggest that you provide your data (stops, connections, times, ...) in the [GTFS format](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) (really easy, based on CSV files) and then use a journey planner such as [OpenTripPlanner](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki). It takes several planning factors into account and can import the GTFS data that you provide. There is also an [Android implementation](https://github.com/marchica/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki) of OpenTripPlanner, but I'm not sure how advanced it is.

**Alternative:**
Other than GTFS/OpenTripPlanner, there is a widely used standard in Europe to model transport information, called [Transmodel](http://www.transmodel.org/), and supporting planning engines like "JourneyWeb". Many local transport providers (including the one in my city) build their services on top of Transmodel. But I think that would be way harder to implement (plus I'm not sure about licenses and free/open implementations), so I'd stick to the above-mentioned solution.